# Oracle Global Temp table - data is truncated but the table remains in the DB ! is this an expected behavior or a configuration?

Tags: oracle, temporary-tables, drop-table

We are trying to create global temp table using

```
    Create global Temporary table t1 ( id NUMBER, description VARCHAR2(20) ) 
ON COMMIT Delete Rows;
```

and trying to drop it at the end manually  but the temp table created cannot be dropped by after but the session the data is truncated at the end.

1. Not able to drop it  - is this how oracle works with GTT ?
2. What are the alternatives ??

Comment: How do you define the table (show the DDL)? How do you drop it? How do you determine that the table remains?

Comment: the table Definition would be  Create global temp table t1 (
  id           NUMBER,
  description  VARCHAR2(20)
)
ON COMMIT DROP DEFINITION;   Drop table t1 ;  -- to identify the table is still there                                                                                                      select *
from all_tables
where TEMPORARY = 'Y'  -- Or even when i try to run the same create query it says object already in the system

Comment: Please use the [edit] button and add relevant information to your question, as comments are ephemeral.

Comment: [works for me](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=bd4d9aeb8d6fbcf8deab653eb49e84c5) ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Yes, I am sure the query will work. My question is if i don't have drop permission , this table should be dropped automatically. But its not dropping automatically at the end of my session. so is it a DB configuration issue? or is it how the temp tables in oracle works.

Comment: "Not able to drop it" is not error message or an exact problem description.

Comment: You misunderstand how GTTs work. Global temporary tables are _not_ dropped automatically. "The temporary table definition persists in the same way as the definitions of regular tables, but the table segment and any data the table contains are either session-specific or transaction-specific data", says the manual.

Comment: cool ,I am new to oracle and its surprising that we have to drop global temp tables manually. if the definition stays in the DB and as developers we do not have permission to drop the tables. there is no point to create temp tables except we can create phy tables and truncate them at the end.

Comment: why would you feel a need to drop a GTT?  The whole point of a GTT is that the _definition_ persists, but the actual segment only exists as needed by a session, thus saving the overhead of repeated CREATE and DROP commands.  I think you are trying to approach GTT as you would structures from some other RDBMS, but that simply does not apply in Oracle.

Comment: i have worked in few DB's like SQL server , Netezza where the skeleton of the table also gets dropped at the end of the session. So  we can use the same temp table name again and again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comments indicate Oracle Global temporary tables work differently than some might expect.  They are intended to be permanent structures.  The settings allow for data to be retained when a session is closed or deleted.

The key reason to use them is that each user can only access data for that user.

Your developers can all use the same table and insert/update/delete without interfering with other users.

There is no need to drop a GTT after using it.